# Speed of sound in thermodynamically unstable phases

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, acoustics

The general thermodynamic definition for the speed of sound is
$$c_S=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right)_{S}}$$

But what if the material is in a non-stable state, e.g. during tension or superheating, where the derivative becomes negative as illustrated in the figure below.

Obviously the general (equilibrium) thermodynamics' definition breaks down here.
Is there an alternative, continuum-mechanical definition for the speed of sound which is also applicable in these states?

I "workaround" I've encountered quite often is to do a Maxwell-construction.
Is this a valid approach?

[image: pressure-specific volume isotherms]

Comment: 'Sounds' like an idea for a research project

Answer (score 0):

Speed of sound depends on the formation of 'elastic waves'. Henceforth, an underlying (quasi)harmonic collective behaviour. I don't think 'traditional waves' happen around such an out of equilibrium configuration, such as superheating or stuff that happen under phase transitions. Perhaps most likely is the formation of solitons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton

As for your second question, only experiment can tell, no matter the beautiful derivations that can justify the use of Maxwell-construction in the case. But, as I can't help, intuition sparks about applying Renormalization Group techniques. If you never heard about it, read this quite decent book [https://www.amazon.com/Renormalization-Methods-William-David-McComb/dp/0199236526](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199236526). It has a chapter (chap.11 I think) on applications to Continuum Dynamics.